# How do I get access to this variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im in the partial `_video.html.erb` which is in the videos directory of the views directory. I know I have access to the `video` variable. I have a video_vote model with a has_many/belongs_to association with Videos and with Users. I also have implemented a current_user method. I want to get access to the current user's vote on that video. How do I do it?

This is in the create method of the `video_votes` controller:

```
@video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
@vote = current_user.video_votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show us your model and controller code.

Comment: I posted the useful part of the VideoVote controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a function in your user model that is something like:

```
class User
  # code
  def num_votes_for(video)

    video_votes.find_by_video_id(video.id)
  end
  # more code
end
```

And in your view, you would do something like

Your number of votes: `<%= current_user.num_votes_for(video) %>`

Comment: that makes sense, but it seems like I'd be able to get what I want without creating anything else new... no?

Comment: Retrieving data with regards to the model should be put into the model, it makes sense to put it here.

Comment: It is in the User model because you are fetching information regarding the user. In this case you are wondering what the current's users vote status is for a given video.

Comment: You want to push this kind of behavior into the models, because it is reusable there.